# What kind of glue can be used to join flat drive belt and v-belt?

Tags: glue

For my special project I need to join flat drive belt with a v-belt (the wider part of it's profile to be precise). Due to the nature of their application such combined part will be rotating with most of the power transfered via the v-belt (it is supposed to be a diy tank track). The joint must be able to bend as the whole contraption will be stretched between two 20cm diameter wheels. I plan to reinforce it with screws or rivets.

Could you please advise what kind of glue can do the job?

Comment: Did you try to do it? Did it work out?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [Shoe Goo](http://www.eclecticproducts.com/shoegoo.htm) ... it dries rubbery and flexible.

Another alternative would be [contact cemement](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00106ETT6) (I use DAP, personally, do *not* get the non-flamable one that cleans up with water), but it's much harder to work with in general.  And they're serious about using it outside -- the fumes are *very* strong.

And my last choice would be basic rubber cement ... the bond's not great, but if you're reinforcing it, it might be okay.  (just don't get the 'repositionable' stuff)

Comment: contact cement is great (fumes aside) and I love using it as an adhesive. Just wanted to add one word of warning, make SURE you're lined up and in position when you put the two surfaces together. It's been my experience that once you seal something with contact cement it won't come apart come hell or high water. Every time I've tried to break apart contact cement it has always resulted in the destruction of one of the pieces. Still love it though.

Comment: @Scott : yeah, I probably should've explained the 'harder to work with', which is basically what you said.  But it holds up to flexing very well; it's what's used for making foam swords for [live wargaming](http://www.darkon.org/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be rolling a v-belt around two rollers, I don't think you can glue a continuous flat belt to it and have it stick. Unless the flat belt is very flexible along the length of it (which is usually exactly what it's designed NOT to do), you might have a problem with the belts flexing differently. If you glue the belts while flat, they won't curve, and if you glue them curved, they'll want to stay curved.

If you get a flat belt and turn it inside out, then you'll be gluing the reinforced tensioning part of the belts together, and it might work. In that case, I'd probably just use contact cement like Joe and Scott say.

Answer (score 0):

This late, is probably too much trouble, and might not work anyway.  Well, I won't let that stop me!

Playing off of @Steve Armstrong's thought that the continuous flat belt probably would stick successfully and given that your application is for a tracked vehicle, how about an approach like this:

Rather than gluing the flat belt to the v-belt, what if you cut the flat belt (or some other material) into chunks, each of which is glued (or otherwise attached) to the flat belt.  So, the "outer" surface of the track is not a continous flat belt, but is segmented.

You might be able to avoid some of the inherent shear that is likely to occur between the continuous flat belt and the v-belt as the "track" rolls around the two (or whatever number you have) rollers.